# Environment variables in parcel nested modules

Tags: nested, environment-variables, undefined, parceljs

I'm trying to use environment variables in "nested" dependencies of a project bundled with Parcel, using `.env` files, but I'm getting `undefined` instead of the desired value.

According to [the docs](https://parceljs.org/env.html), `NODE_ENV` is automatically set to "*production*" when building, else it's set to "*development*", so it will load `.env.local` either `.env.production` depending on that value.

Consider my file structure:

```
./
├── .env.local
├── .env.production
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   └── APIService.js
└── package.json
```

My script for launching the app in `package.json` is this:

```json
   "scripts": {
      "start": "parcel src/index.html"
   }
```

… and the `src/index.html` file loads the `main.js` file with a simple  tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- ... -->

<script src="main.js" defer></script>
```

If I try to log an environment variable set in `.env.local` in `main.js`, it will work perfectly because it is the JS entry point, but if I try to get the same exact variable into an imported module like `APIService.js`, I get `undefined`:

```js
// main.js

import APIService from "./APIService";

console.log(process.env.API_ENDPOINT); // ✅ http://localhost:5001/functions/app
```

```js
// APIService.js

console.log(process.env.API_ENDPOINT); // ❌ undefined
```

Am I missing something?

How to get access to the environment variables inside imported files?

PS: I've already tried to use the `dotenv` package in addition, but without success.